# Shebang (#!) not working in script after Python reinstallation

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, shebang

I have 2 versions of Python 2.7 and 3.7 in Windows. Everything was working fine before I reinstalled both of them, but now when I want python to run 3.7, it just defaults to 2.7.

I have tried

```
#!/usr/bin/python3 
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#!python3
```

I also have played around with the 
Environment variables

```
PATH
PY_PYTHON
```

and none of them are working.

Also, if I just install the 3.7 version by itself, Python does not recognize the .py file formats by default (unrecognized file icons), that is until I install 2.7. So, I cant open the file from the command line without using 'py'. I think the solution to why it defaults to 2.7 can be explained by this, I just dont know how to fix it.

Comment: "I also have played around with the Environment variables" please add the content of `PATH` to your question and what you have tried.

Comment: just the direct path to my python directory (i.e. C:/code/python3/python, C:/code/python3), this is the right path as I consulted 'where python'. Also PY_PYTHON value = 3, although this command only affects my 'py' executable even before I had this issue (so i guess thats another problem, which may tie into this one?), if opening the files directly (even without a #! script and used PY_PYTHON = 3), it always defaulted to 2.7